# The best XMLEditor available

Tags: xml, xsd, editor

I am using an old version of Altova's XMLSpy and it often freezes. Do you know an alternative XMLEditor (free or not, web or windows) that I could use to write XML documents based on a XSD file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend [Oxygen XML Editor](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oxygenxml.com%2F&ei=81BlTYC0IYGy8QPasrn9Bg&usg=AFQjCNHvxl5dr3pwqTJuCCc6FUvKIBXqbA&sig2=y6_KSfRiMBF33rNxNDefHA).

Answer (score 1):

I love XML Spy too, even if it is pricey.

I can also recommend Liquid XML.

http://www.liquid-technologies.com/

Answer (score 0):

I still love XMLSpy. But Microsoft's [XML notepad](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=72d6aa49-787d-4118-ba5f-4f30fe913628&displaylang=en) isn't half bad.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Altova's XMLSpy - It's the best around!

Plus, if you have a support and maintenance package from them, you get free updates (they realease a new version/service pack 3-4 times per year with new features).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with [PSGML mode](http://www.lysator.liu.se/projects/about_psgml.html), and it does the job quite nicely. Setting things up and getting it all working can be challenging, but Emacs is widely used, very robust, and (with the right expertise) quite extensible. Plus, both Emacs and the PSGML mode package are open source.

Comment: It would be impossible because some of the users are non-technical.